# Semi-advanced logic inside Vuex getter

Tags: for-loop, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

How much logic can be used inside a vuex getter? Where is the line drawn for what is bad practice?

Example code:

```
totalShippingFee: state => {
  let newTotalShippingFee = 0;

   for (let i = 0; i < state.shippingFees.length; i += 1) {
      newTotalShippingFee += state.shippingFees[i].fee;
   }

   return newTotalShippingFee;
}
```

Is it okay to have a for loop and this much logic inside this vuex getter?

Comment: I think this is fine (you can simplify it to a reduce but that's a whole other topic). Evan actually has a demo "shopping cart" in the Vuex examples if you care to look: https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/tree/dev/examples/shopping-cart

Comment: `totalShippingFee: state => state.shippingFees.reduce((total, feeDetails) => total + feeDetails.fee, 0)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Altough we generally avoid heavy logic into getters and setters in OOP languages, it's another story in Vue.

The code you provided is a completely valid use case for a getter in Vue. Vue caches the result until something change, which is a pretty nice feature for any "intensive" calculation.